# soapUI Dynamic mock service: How to extract response name from request parameter?

Tags: xpath, soap, groovy, mocking, soapui

I am trying to build a mock service in SoapUI, which dynamically returns a response, based on a value passed in the request. Example:

```
<foo>
     <bar>
        <ID>Response1</ID>  <--- I want to extract this
        <ReferenceID>stuff</ReferenceID>
        <CreationDate>2016-05-01T11:34:56Z</CreationDate>
     </bar>
</foo>
```

So I set my DISPATCH to SCRIPT and tried the following (the return value should specify the name of the response, which is returned):

```
def req = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
return "${req.foo.bar.ID}"
```

And this:

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent )
def arg1 = holder.getNodeValue("ID") // also tried "//ID"
return arg1.toString();
```

Neither worked, the mock always returns the default response - hope some of you can help me with the solution :)

Comment: May be your request might have some namespaces which why it might help when you tried `//ID`. Probably you want to give a try with `//*:ID`?

Comment: "//*:ID" worked in my second approach. Thanks Rao :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your `<foo>` response is wrapped in a *SOAP*`<envelope>` and `<body>` so the path you're using with `XmlSlurper` is not correct `req.foo.bar.ID`.

Furthermore if in your case your response is not wrapper with `<envelope>` and `<body>` note that in the `XmlSlurper` the `root` node starts at the object itself so the `req.foo` is not needed since `<foo>` is the root node, looks at the follow example:

```
def xml = 
'''<foo>
     <bar>
        <ID>Response1</ID>
        <ReferenceID>stuff</ReferenceID>
        <CreationDate>2016-05-01T11:34:56Z</CreationDate>
     </bar>
</foo>
'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
println slurper.foo // prints nothing...
println slurper.bar.ID // prints Response1
```

Due to this maybe the easy way to get the node value is to use [`find`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find()) method, so in your DISPATCH script:

```
def req = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
return req.'**'.find { it.name() == 'ID' }
```

Alternatively if you want to use `XmlHolder` instead of `XmlSlurper` as @Rao comments simply use a namespace on your *XPath*. Fortunately *SOAPUI* allows you to use `*` as a wildcard for namespaces so correct `ID` by `//*:ID`:

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent )
return holder.getNodeValue("//*:ID").toString()
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: "//*:ID" worked in my second approach. Thanks albciff :)